# Remove everything but the first column in VIM

Tags: vim, editing

I have a text file and I want to remove every word except the first word on every line and I have no idea how to do this.

So, if I have:

```
one two three
four five
six
```

I want to remain with:

```
one
four
six
```

Got any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the lines don't start with whitespace, you could replace `' .*'` (which matches everything after the first word) with an empty string:

```
:%s/ .*//g
```

Answer (score 7):

A more robust solution is to filter it through a program that is really good at these kinds of manipulations: `awk`.

Say you had this content:

```
one two three

  four five
            six
```

Run `:%!awk '{print $1}'` and you will get:

```
one

four
six
```

`awk`'s default field separator character is a space, though you could change it to whatever you wanted, depending on what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can do it using a macro.
Type `qa` in normal mode to start recording a macro in register a.
Then type `0elDj` to delete everything on the current line but the first word, and go to the next line.
Type `q` again to end recording the macro.

Now you can fire the macro on any line with `@a`.
Run `:%norm! @a` to apply the macro to every line in the buffer.

This way you can repeat any complex operation you want, not just substituting.
I love macros :)

EDIT: Note that it doesn't work when a line has strictly less than 2 characters. For this reason, this is generally not the best approach to this problem.